# How to run exported ionic project through terminal

Tags: ionic-framework

I have code from another developer, now I want to build that project on my system.
so what should be the steps for that.
I have this files and folders in my src folder.[image]

Comment: Finally you should get `.apk` file for android and you can run it on simulator in Android Studio. If you don't get this file in built project, than your config is wrong.

Comment: I am not able to run this project. How to configure this project in my blank app. I don't know which file to edit.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know too, I only know which result should be...

Answer (score 0):

If your Ionic environment developer is okay, also check if Node is installed.

```
run npm install
```

If not:

```
sudo npm install -g ionic cordova
```

After this:

```
ionic serve
```

To run in your browser...

Comment: I have installed everything, just the thing is I don't know how to set this project's login page as start page of my Blank App.

Comment: You can do it on app.component.ts. Like this: `rootPage: any = LoginPage;`